# Is there any point to playing the arcade game in the bar?

Tags: starcraft-2

In campaign mode, do you get something special if you beat the Lost Viking arcade game? (can it be beat?)

Comment: Is there any point to playing Starcraft II in your room? In life, do you get something special if you beat the SC2 campaign? ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get achievements. And the text of the achievements would seem to suggest it can be beat.

- Terra-tron Terrorized! (10)
  Beat the Terra-tron on the Lost Viking arcade machine.
- Lost Viking: Bronze (10)
  Score 125,000 points on the Lost Viking arcade machine.
- Lost Viking: Silver (10)
  Score 250,000 points on the Lost Viking arcade machine.
- Lost Viking: Gold (10)
  Score 500,000 points on the Lost Viking arcade machine.

[Source](http://www.starcraft-source.com/achievement/category/view/?id=35)

Comment: And if anyone from Blizzard is reading this: I hate you for making these achievements. :)

Comment: I actually hate them for making it such a lousy game. Man, even amateur game programming contest submissions have better gameplay.

Comment: The games lots of fun, and ya it can be beat (don't hold down the space bar shoots to slow that way). I just got gold on it quite fun. @Grzegorz Adam Hankiewicz sure it kinda sucks, but it was meant as an example of what can be done with the engine.

Comment: The [Metal Slug Starcraft 2 video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAvZlonNTDg) is a WAY more impressive proof of concept, and also made by a community member, not staff. I think.

Comment: For those interested -- it takes about 9 levels to get gold.

Comment: @JavadocMD: agree! @Viper: as an example for what could be done with the engine they should have done minesweeper! :)

Comment: @Grzegorz I have a feeling they made that game primarily as a demonstration to what the galaxy editor can do, as a way to tease players into giving custom map-making a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you load the "Maw of the Void Victory" autosave then it will load a cinematic that you can skip and it will bring you straight to the bridge.